# Solving this equation

Tags: exponentiation, quadratic-forms, rational-numbers, number-systems

**Question**:

> Solve: $$3^{2x^2}-2\cdot3^{x^2+x+6}+3^{2(x+6)}=0$$

I thought that we can take $a=3^{x^2}$ and $b = 3^{x+6}$. Then equation becomes $a^2-2ab+b^2=0$, which obviously means $a-b=0$. Substituing, I got:

$$3^{x^2}-3^{x+6}=0$$

But, I can't proceed further. I have an intuition that this is quadratic equation, but can't figure out how to. Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $3^{x} = 3^y$, then $x=y$. In your case, you have $3^{x^2} = 3^{x+6}$.

Comment: Was it that simple! I can't believe I failed to notice such a  thing ! Thanks a lot. Acceptance in 11 minutes ;)

Comment: Sometimes, it's the simple and obvious parts that we miss... :)